# How to implement java template method design pattern for image objects: BufferedImage, Image, ImageIcon

Tags: java, class, design-patterns, methods, abstract-class

What would be an example of `template method design pattern` for image objects, or different types of image like: `BufferedImage`, `Image`, `ImageIcon`. I only need java class methods and their signatures and fields i don't need real functional code. this would be based on the fact that different types of image have same mechanisms for displaying titles but different mechanisms for displaying images.

Comment: Are you asking for a new class that exemplifies the pattern or for an existing example on those classes? Your question is really unclear as it stands. Also, this really feels like a "start writing my code for me" question, which isn't a good fit for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Theory:

The template method pattern let's you define the skeleton of an algorithm in a method of the superclass, the so-called *template method*.

From within this template method, one or more abstract methods are invoked to accomplish some steps of the algorithm. This abstract methods are sometimes referred to as *placeholder methods*.

Since they're abstract, these steps have no implementation in the superclass. Instead, they are implemented by subclasses in different ways, so that invoking the inherited template method on a specific subclass instance will run the algorithm with the placeholders it provides.

### Implementation:

Consider the usage of *generics* to implement a more robust template pattern, as well as defining the placeholder methods as `protected`, since they're meant to be invoked only from within the template method.

If you don't want to let subclasses override the template method, declare it as `final` in the abstract superclass.

I assume that both `BufferedImage` and `ImageIcon` from your example are subclasses of `Image` and that the template method (the algorithm) must display an image with its title:

```
// Class that defines the template method
// Generic parameter allows to define the specific type of image
// that will be handled by this image renderer
public abstract class ImageRenderer<T extends Image> {

    // This is the template method
    // It's final to avoid that subclasses override it
    public final void display(String title, T image) {
        // Display title
        this.displayTitle(title);
        // Let subclasses display specific type of image
        this.displayImage(image);
    }

    // Display title for every image type
    // This method is private since it's only called
    // from within the template method
    // (make it protected if you want to let subclasses 
    // override it, i.e. for custom title displaying)
    private void displayTitle(String title) {
        // Display title, no matter the image type
    }

    // Placeholder method, no implementation
    // Actual implementation is delegated to subclasses
    protected abstract void displayImage(T image);
}
```

The class `BufferedImageRenderer` would need to provide an implementation to the `displayImage()` method, by overriding it. Here's where generics is of great help, since `displayImage()` method arguments don't need to be *downcasted*:

```
public class BufferedImageRenderer 
    extends ImageRenderer<BufferedImage> {

    @Override
    protected void displayImage(BufferedImage image) {
        // Display specific buffered image
    }
}
```

And the same considerations apply to the `ImageIconRenderer` class:

```
public class ImageIconRenderer 
    extends ImageRenderer<ImageIcon> {

    @Override
    protected void displayImage(ImageIcon image) {
        // Display specific image icon
    }
}
```

Then, whenever you need to display a specific image along with its title, just create the appropriate renderer and invoke the template method, i.e. for an `ImageIcon`:

```
ImageIcon icon = getImageIconFromSomePlace();
String iconTitle = "My pretty icon";

ImageIconRenderer renderer = new ImageIconRenderer();
renderer.displayImage(iconTitle, icon);
```

Thanks to generics, if you attempted to invoke `displayImage()` with an image that the renderer cannot handle, you'd get a comnpilation error:

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = getBufferedImageFromSomePlace();
String bufferedImageTitle = "My amazing buffered image";

ImageIconRenderer renderer = new ImageIconRenderer();
renderer.displayImage(bufferedImageTitle, bufferedImage); // compilation error
```

Answer (score 2):

the template method pattern is a behavioral design pattern that defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in a method.

Smalltalk's printString is a template method.

I suppose there is a draw(Graphics g) method in java which is also a template method.

In your case too, you can have a following draw template method in the parent class. The sub classes implementing this method can define their own algorithm to draw the image

```
public void draw(Image i);
```

Example

```
   class Image {
        int x1,y1,x2,y2; // may be boundaries of image common to all inherited 
objects
        String title;

        protected void displayTitle() {

        }
        // some code goes here
        public void draw() {
             // some code common to all image drawing
             // this might involve x and y declared above
             displayTitle();
             drawImage();
             // some more code after the template method
        }
        // the subclasses inheriting define their own algorithm to display image
        public abstract void drawImage();
    }

    class BufferedImage extends Image {
        // defines its own algorithm    
        public void drawImage() {
            // BufferedImage specific code to display the image
        }
    }

    class IconImage extends Image {
        // defines its own algorithm
        public void drawImage() {
            // IconImage specific code to display the image
        }
    }

    class DriverProgram {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Image[] image = {new BufferedImage(),new IconImage(),new XYXImage()};
            for(Image img:image) {
                img.draw();  // calling the template method
            }
        }
    }
```

as I said above template method defines a skeleton of algorithm which subclasses should implement. It is one of the beautiful design pattern to know.

Comment: "Java's toString() method is a template method.". No it does not define any algorithm skeleton.

Comment: Your `Image:: draw` is actually a template method.

Comment: @gontard you are right, toString() of java is not a template method, I mixed it up with smalltalk's printString method which is a template method. Edited my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

In software engineering, the template method pattern is a behavioral design pattern that defines the program skeleton of an algorithm in a method, called template method, which defers some steps to subclasses. It lets one redefine certain steps of an algorithm without changing the algorithm's structure.

First you need to declare an abstract class, which will be inherited by other image classes.
It declares one abstract method meant to be implemented by other classes
and one method that will be inherited by classes that implement this abstract class:

```
public abstract class Template{    
    public String imageTitle;
    abstract public void displayImage(JLabel label); //abstract unimplemented method
    public void displayTitle(String imageTitle)
    {
        //Implement your display title method for all classes
    }       
}
```

Then you can define your classes to implement the abstract method:

```
public class ImageIconClass extends Template{
    @Override
    public void displayImage(JLabel label) {
        // Implement specific display image method for ImageIconClass       
    }
}

public class ImageClass extends Template{
    @Override
    public void displayImage(JLabel label) {
         // Implement specific display image method for ImageClass          
    }
}

public class BufferedImageClass extends Template{
     @Override
    public void displayImage(JLabel label) {
       // Implement specific display image method for BufferedImageClass        
    }    
}
```

Jlabel is used to display the image.

Comment: Where's the template method?

Comment: According to me this is not a template method. Both displayImage() and displayTitle() are NOT template.

Comment: @Prasad Shinde can you explain way do you think so? and what do you mean by "Both displayImage() and displayTitle() are NOT template." Template method design pattern is composed of entities like classes that inherit properties from a superclass. In this case superclass can have one or more abstract methods (displayImage) wich are ment to be implemented by classes that inherit the superclass. Super class also has methods (displayTitle) that are common to all classes that extend a superclass.  That is the basics of template method. Basically template method is a wrapper class.